# Calling ajax inside of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call that gets a type of a property. Using that type I then pass it into another ajax call. I'm having some difficulty doing this asynchronously because I'm trying to defer til the first property is loaded.

```
function getEnt_PodType() {
    var ent_PodType;
    var oDataUrl = //URL to my data;
    return $.ajax({
        url: oDataUrl,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
        },
        success: function (xhr, textStatus) { 
            var res = xhr;
            if (res.d.results != undefined) {
                ent_PodType = res.d.results[0].Ent_PodType;
            }
            console.log("The ent pod type value is "+ ent_PodType);
            return ent_PodType;
        }
    });
}

function getProjects() {

    var QUERY_FILTER = getEnt_PodType().done(function (result) {
        "$filter=Ent_PodType eq '" + result + "'";
    });

    var url = restUrl + QUERY_FILTER;

    console.log("The url form getProjects is " + QUERY_FILTER);

    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
        },
        success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            projects = parseODataResultTest(xhr);
            return projects;
        }
    });

}
```

When I call the getProjects(), I thought building the url would wait for getEnt_PodType() to return its value but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Instead it goes ahead and executes the rest of getProjects(). Is there any way to do this asynchronously?

Comment: You need to do the second AJAX call inside the `.done()` function.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. Anything that depends on the result must be done in the callback function.

I also recommend always passing the parameters as an object, to allow jQuery to encode it properly.

```
function getProjects() {

    getEnt_PodType().done(function (result) {
        var QUERY_FILTER = { "$filter": "Ent_PodType eq '" + result + "'"};

        console.log("The url form getProjects is " + QUERY_FILTER);

        return $.ajax({
            url: restUrl,
            data: QUERY_FILTER,
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
            },
            success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                projects = parseODataResultTest(xhr);
                return projects;
            }
        });
    });



}
```

Comment: The result within getEnt_PodType().done(function (result) gets returned as [object Object]. However, it does execute correctly within getEnt_PodType method. Why is it returning [object Object]?

Comment: Sounds like the AJAX server is returning JSON, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your second ajax call need to be placed inside done promise. You can wrap rest of your code in local function and call it inside done, like so:

```
function getProjects() {

  function getProjectsViaAjax(){
     var url = restUrl + QUERY_FILTER;

     console.log("The url form getProjects is " + QUERY_FILTER);

     return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
        },
        success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            projects = parseODataResultTest(xhr);
            return projects;
        }
      }); 
    }; // end of getProjectsViaAjax

   var QUERY_FILTER = getEnt_PodType().done(function (result) {
        "$filter=Ent_PodType eq '" + result + "'";
         getProjectsViaAjax();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call needs to be in the `done` promise. Something like the following should be ok.

```
function getProjects() {

    return  getEnt_PodType().done(function (result) {
        var QUERY_FILTER = "$filter=Ent_PodType eq '" + result + "'";
        var url = restUrl + QUERY_FILTER;

        console.log("The url form getProjects is " + QUERY_FILTER);

        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
            },
            success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                projects = parseODataResultTest(xhr);
                return projects;
            }
    });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to call the second code from the success function of first code.Or you put the code in a function and call that function from the success callback of first ajax call.Using .done calllback is more appropriate.So call second function from done callback of first ajax call.

```
function getProjects() {

    return  getEnt_PodType().done(function (result) {
        var QUERY_FILTER = "$filter=Ent_PodType eq '" + result + "'";
        var url = restUrl + QUERY_FILTER;

        console.log("The url form getProjects is " + QUERY_FILTER);

       return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("ACCEPT", accept);
        },
        success: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            projects = parseODataResultTest(xhr);
            return projects;
        }
     });

  });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call one function synchronously, because second task is depends on first task. 
You can call function **getEnt_PodType** synchronously, you need to make
**async: false** in this function. 
And then it will work as you expected.